# How to check if a PostgreSQL logical replication slot already exists with java?

Tags: java, postgresql, database-replication

I'm creating a logical replication slot with Java code using the PostgreSQL replication API and I want to add a test before the creation  process to check if the  slot exists already. 
this is my code :

```
connection.getReplicationAPI()
.createReplicationSlot()
.logical()
.withSlotName(slotName)
.withOutputPlugin("test_decoding")
.make();
```

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-replication-slots.html

Comment: Thank you and again please mention it as answer :D

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  slot_name,
  plugin,
  slot_type,
  datoid,
  database,
  temporary,
  active,
  active_pid,
  xmin,
  catalog_xmin,
  restart_lsn,
  confirmed_flush_lsn
FROM pg_replication_slots
WHERE slot_name = ?
```

Comment: Consider adding some prose to your answer, so as to create a more useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check it by following way:

```
    log.info("creating replication slot, slotName={}", slotName);
try {
  connection.getReplicationAPI()
      .createReplicationSlot()
      .logical()
      .withSlotName(slotName)
      .withOutputPlugin("test_decoding")
      .make();
  log.info("replication slot created");
} catch (Exception e) {
  if (e.getMessage()
      .equals("ERROR: replication slot \"" + slotName
          + "\" already exists")) {
    log.info("replication slot exists, not creating");
  } else {
    log.error("error creating replication slot", e);
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
}
```